# Angular js - change value of model in custom directive

Tags: angularjs

i m trying to change ng-model value in custom directive but issue is that i have used controller as

```
<div ng-controller="AreaController as vm">
<md-input-container flex="40" class="md-block" on-enter="vm.search()">
            <label>Search</label>  
              <md-icon class="material-icons" >search</md-icon>  
            <input type="text" name="search" ng-model="vm.area.searchText" clear-input="vm.getList()">
            </md-input-container>
```

and in custom directive, i m trying to clear input field by changing ng-model value to '' but i m unable to get value

```
   var result = scope[attr.ngModel];
                    var r = $parse(attr.ngModel);
```

result is null, how can i fix this issue

any help will be appreciated

Comment: if you console.log the scope in your directive do you see a value for ngModel or clearList?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the `ngModel` value in your custom directive by accessing the `ngModel` controller's `$viewValue` and `$modelValue` properties:

```
angular.module('app').directive('clearInput', clearInputDirective)

var clearInputDirective = function(){
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      require: "ngModel",
      link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel){
         var view_value = ngModel.$viewValue; //The actual value from the control's view
         var model_value = ngModel.$modelValue; //The value in the model that the control is bound to
         ngModel.$viewValue = 'new value'; //Set new view value
         ngModel.$commitViewValue(); //Commit a pending update to the $modelValue
      }
    }   

 }
```

Comment: thanks it provides value but i m trying to update . i have tried using  ngModel.$setViewValue(null); but it doesn't work the way as expected . it doesnt update value

Comment: You should commit changes after use `ngModel.$setViewValue()`. `$commitViewValue()` - Commit a pending update to the $modelValue

Comment: You can also set model value direct - assign value to `ngModel.$viewValue` and then use `ngModel.$commitViewValue()`

Comment: i fixed it using ngModel.$render()